# MySQL WorkBench vs CC Can't connect to server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, control-center

I managed to connect to 192.168.0.253 with MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver installed using Control Center but when I switch to Work Bench, it gives me the following error, `Malformed Packet`

If I use the Control Centre I am good to connect. Please help

**WorkBench**
[image]

**Control Center**
[image: Control Center]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This MySQL server version is way too old. MySQL Workbench currently supports MySQL server 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0.